# Why doesn't SQLAlchemy update a row value in my Flask WSGI server?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am creating a testing web-application and each time a user submits a question correct, the `incorrect` or `correct` method will be called, giving the `user` passed in `+1` of the `totalattempted` in that respective row.

```
def incorrect(user):
    u = user
    u.totalattempted += 1
    session.commit()
    u.score = round(u.totalcorrect * u.totalcorrect / u.totalattempted)
    session.commit()

def correct(user):
    u = user
    u.totalattempted += 1
    session.commit()
    u.totalcorrect += 1
    session.commit()
    u.score = round(u.totalcorrect * u.totalcorrect / u.totalattempted)
    session.commit()
```

The issue that I have is when the `correct` method is called several times per second, the server will correctly give the user +1 to its `totalcorrect` but will not give +1 to it's total attempted. I almost feel like this issue may be server-wide as when a user's account is created, there is about a 30 second delay before the server detects that user's account. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is prone to race conditions. Incrementing the value on a model updates the database with the new value. It does not perform an atomic update. To do that:

```
u.totalattempted = User.totalattempted + 1
```

The same should be done for `totalcorrect`.

Also, you probably shouldn't commit between updating each field. That causes SQLAlchemy to flush the session and reload the record when you update `totalcorrect`.